# Weyl Large Number Coincidence

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology

I've just learned of the Weyl Large Number Coincidence on the Wikipedia. It looks interesting. Here is my interpretation of it.

What is the smallest "quantum" of energy in the Universe?
$$E_{min} = \hbar H$$
where $H$ is the Hubble parameter. This make sense as the Hubble parameter is roughly the inverse of the age of the Universe ($H=2\times10^{-18}s^{-1}$). You can't define a non-zero frequency smaller than that.

Now consider the gravitational self-energy of a particle, $E_g$, given by
$$E_g = \frac{Gm^2}{r}$$ where $m$, $r$ is the mass,size of the particle.
The smallest possible particle must have a gravitational self-energy of the size of $E_{min}$ therefore we have
$$\frac{Gm^2}{r} = \hbar H$$

We can link the mass $m$ and size $r$ of a particle by using the Compton wavelength quantum relation
$$m c r = \hbar$$

Putting the two equations together and eliminating $r$ we find

$$m^3 = \frac{\hbar^2H}{Gc}$$

If we plug values into this expression we get a mass given by

$$m \approx 10^{-28}kg$$

This is nearish to the proton mass.

Interesting or just a coincidence?

Comment: So put another way, the age of the universe is $\approx \hbar^2/Gcm_\mathrm{p}^3$, which is constant. So would we even be asking this at any other point in the history (or future) of the universe?

Comment: It is interesting, because it sparks your curiosity and lets your mind wonder to all sorts of corners. But Weyl's Large numbers and say Dirac's large numbers hypothesis are just coincidences for now. Maybe in the future, things and theories will be different and could account for "stuff" like this. In the present, this is just **numerology**.

Comment: For every operation you add, you need more matching digits to confirm it because the number of possibilities goes way up and allows you to find equations that approximately match by brute luck. Your expression has a handful of operations and only matches *one* digit of the *exponent*. That implies, as a starting point, that it's a coincidence.

Answer (score 7):

The correct elimination in SI (or other everyday) units includes an extra $c$ you forgot,
$$m^3 = \frac{\hbar^2 H}{Gc} $$
which gives $m\sim 1.1\times 10^{-28}$ kilograms which is just 0.065 of the proton mass. It's not terribly close, it is? If you got much less, you would find another nearby particle mass or something like that.

At any rate, in the Planck units, this calculated mass is just $m=H^{1/3}$, a particular fractional power of the Hubble constant. The Planck mass (1 in Planck units) is much heavier than elementary particles, some micrograms or so, but the positive power of $H\sim 10^{-60}$ in the Planck units reduces is to the proton mass (approximately). You could design other arguments that would pick another power of $H$ and get pretty much anywhere you want to get.

So unless you show otherwise, it is a coincidence.

Comment: At recombination time when the Universe was only 1/1000 size then the limiting value m=10^-27 kg. Maybe protons just couldn't exist before this time.

Comment: Dear @John, I assure you that protons existed much earlier than that - at least since the time when the temperature of the universe was comparable to the nuclear scale (nuclei were born in the first three minutes after the Big Bang, the so-called nucleogenesis, and protons really existed before that, since "baryogenesis", at least the baryon charge did). Your equation only says that the mutual proton-proton gravitational energy is comparable to the Hubble contribution. But both of them are negligible relatively to the non-gravitational energies (nuclear, electro) that actually mattered.

Comment: Point taken! Maybe I should have said neutral hydrogen atoms rather than bare protons.